# Qt Serial Port Write and Read Issues

Tags: qt, serial-port

I have two hardware communicating over serial ports. The two hardware have their own instance of Serial Port Class. I'm having trouble with WaitForLineAvailable() returning an empty string. And sometimes Segmentation error on WaitForBytesWriten() line of the Write() method. These issues are random. I don't understand what might cause this kind of behaviour. Looking for some suggestions here.

SerialPortClass.cpp

```
bool SerialPortClass::OpenCommunicationsPort(QString port, QString params)
{
QMutexLocker locker(&mutexOpenCommunicationsPort);

if(SerialPort != nullptr)
{
    if(SerialPort->isOpen()) SerialPort->close();

    SerialPort->setPortName(port);
}
else
    SerialPort = new QSerialPort(port);

// split up params "230400 N 8 1"
QStringList paramsList = params.split(" ");

if(paramsList.size() == 4)
{
    SerialPort->setBaudRate(paramsList.value(0).toInt());
    if (paramsList.value(1) == "N") { SerialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity); }
    if (paramsList.value(1) == "E") { SerialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::EvenParity); }
    if (paramsList.value(1) == "O") { SerialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::OddParity); }
    if (paramsList.value(2) == "8") { SerialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8); }
    if (paramsList.value(2) == "7") { SerialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data7); }
    if (paramsList.value(3) == "1") { SerialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop); }
    if (paramsList.value(3) == "2") { SerialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::TwoStop); }
    if (mydebug == 1) { qDebug() << "Port Opened on " << port << " " << params; }
    return SerialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
}

return false;
}

    bool SerialPortClass::Write(QString Tx, bool bDelayPerChar)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutexSerialPort);
    
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    
        bool status = true;
    
        QByteArray baTxMsg = Tx.QString::toUtf8();
    
        foreach(char c, baTxMsg)
            {
                SerialPort->write(&c, 1);           
                SerialPort->waitForBytesWritten(200);
                if(bDelayPerChar) { QThread::msleep(5); }
            }
    
        qDebug() << "Tx:" << Tx;
    
        return status;
    }
    
    bool SerialPortClass::WaitForLineAvailable(QString& Rx, int iWaitTime, QString terminator)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutexSerialPort);
    
        Rx = "";
        int delay = 500;
        int retries = (iWaitTime *1000)/delay;
        /*int retries = 30;
        char buffer[128];*/
    
        while ( (!Rx.contains(terminator) ) && (retries > 0) )
        {            
            if (SerialPort->waitForReadyRead(delay))
                //if (SerialPort->waitForReadyRead(5000))
            {
                QByteArray responseData = SerialPort->readAll();
    
                while (SerialPort->waitForReadyRead(50))
                {
                    responseData += SerialPort->readAll();
                }
                Rx = QString::fromUtf8(responseData);
            }
            retries--;
        }
        qDebug() << "Rx:" << Rx << "" << retries;
    
        if (retries > 0)
            return true;
    
        return false;
    }
```

HardwareThread1.h

```
#ifndef HARDWARETHREAD1_H
#define HARDWARETHREAD1_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "serialportclass.h"

class HardwareThread1 : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit HardwareThread1 ( QObject *parent = nullptr );
~HardwareThread1 ();

void go();
void run();
void stop();
void CloseSerialComms();
private:
SerialPortClass serialPort;

bool    GetStopControllerTestFlag();
bool    GetIsShutdownSequenceRunningFlag();
bool    EstablishComms();
bool    m_bCommsEstablished = false;    
int     m_iPSUStatus;
int     m_iIEEEAddress;
QString m_sComPort = "";
QString m_sPortParams = "";
QString m_sRxMsg = "";    
signals:
void signalDisplayPowered(int status, QString sHardware);
void signalDisplayErrorMessage(QString sMessageBoxWindowTitle, QString sMessageBoxWindowText);
void signalUserMessageBox(QString sText1, QString sText2, int iIcon, int iBtn = QMessageBox::Close);
void signalToRunShutdownSequence();
};

#endif // HARDWARETHREAD1_H
```

HardwareThread1.cpp

```
#include "hardwarethread1.h"
#include "globals.h"
#include "programsettingsclass.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

//extern variables//
extern ProgramSettingsClass *pProgramSettingsClassObj;

HardwareThread1::HardwareThread1(QObject *parent) :
QThread(parent)
{
bool bStatus;
m_bCommsEstablished = false;

bStatus = EstablishComms();   
}

/*!

@brief Destructor for the thread.
*/
HardwareThread1::~HardwareThread1()
{
this->terminate();
this->wait();
}
/*!

@brief Attempt to open serial port.

@param in port COM port number to open.

@param in params Serial port parameters.

@return Port open successfully
*/
bool HardwareThread1::EstablishComms()
{
if (m_bCommsEstablished == false)
{
this->m_sComPort = pProgramSettingsClassObj->GetCOMPortSetting("ARDUINO_UNO_HW"); // Get port number for this PSU from settings file list.

     this->m_sPortParams = pProgramSettingsClassObj->GetCOMPortParameters("ARDUINO_UNO_HW");

     if (serialPort.OpenCommunicationsPort(this->m_sComPort, m_sPortParams)) // Attempt to open COM port.
         {
             m_bCommsEstablished =  true;
         }
     else // Could not open COM port.
         {                    
             m_bCommsEstablished =  false;
         }
 }

 return m_bCommsEstablished;
}

/*!

@brief Close Serial Port Comms
*/
void HardwareThread1::CloseSerialComms()
{
serialPort.Close();
}
void HardwareThread1::go()
{
this->start();
}

/*!

@brief Retrieve 'change in Stop Controller Flag'.
@return Flag
*/
bool HardwareThread1::GetStopControllerTestFlag()
{
bool bGet;
mutexGlobalVariable.lock();
bGet = g_bStopControllerTestFlag;
mutexGlobalVariable.unlock();
return bGet;
}
bool HardwareThread1::GetIsShutdownSequenceRunningFlag()
{
bool bGet;
mutexShutdownSequenceVariable.lock();
bGet = g_bIsShutdownSequenceRunning;
mutexShutdownSequenceVariable.unlock();
return bGet;
}

/*!

@brief Timed PSU monitoring.

Checks and sets voltage and current.
*/
void HardwareThread1::run()
{
while(true)
{
bool status = serialPort.IsOpen();

 if ((status) && (!g_bManualValveBeingOperatedFlag) && (!GetStopControllerTestFlag()))
{           
    serialPort.ClearReadBuffer();
              
    serialPort.Write("Clear\n",true);
              
    serialPort.Write("HOOD?\n",true);
              
    serialPort.WaitForLineAvailable(m_sRxMsg); // Wait for response.
               
    m_sRxMsg.remove("\r");
    m_sRxMsg.remove("\n");
    int iHoodStatus = m_sRxMsg.toInt();

    //qDebug() << "HOOD_STAT=" << m_sRxMsg << "\n";

    if((iHoodStatus == 0) && (m_sRxMsg != "")) //The hood is open, hence cut power supply and vent all pressure //
    {
        //Set the global flag//
        mutexGlobalVariable.lock();
        g_bStopControllerTestFlag = true;
        mutexGlobalVariable.unlock();

        //qDebug() << "HOOD_STAT=" << iHoodStatus << "\n";
        emit signalDisplayErrorMessage("Hood Status", "Hood Open Detected!\n \nThe Program will Quit Now.");
         
        CloseArduinoSerialComms();                            
    }
}
QThread::msleep(500);
}
}

void HardwareThread1::stop()
{
this->terminate();
this->wait();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the segfault is coming from waitForBytesWritten()? That seems unlikely. A couple notes: I'd recommend checking the return value of waitForBytesWritten(), and checking for an error if the value is false. Also: is there a reason you need to write one byte at a time?

Comment: Yes I am sure I have seen Seg Errors. That's why I now added the mutex in the methods. After adding the mutexes I have not been able to do a full test run as my Rx string is empty!! I think it should one byte at a time as the hardware on the other side is expecting byte by byte data on the serial line.